# VSTO Alternatives

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-interop

What alternatives exist for VSTO?

What does managedxll do that VSTO does not - When would you use one vs the other

Google does not bring much up on this subject

This is more of an interview question - What are the pros and cons and both is the crux of the question here

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you could tell us more about what you want to do or what features you are looking for.  Or alternatively, what about VSTO makes you want alternatives?

Comment: One alternative is to use VB.NET instead of C# (excluding 4.0) with VSTO. It is much much easier. Yet, as RBarryYoung mentions, we need more information.

Comment: Is VSTO stable reliable and useful?  I remember reading severe criticisms about this but cant remember what they were

Comment: +1 you should accept one of these answers, the ExcelDna tip is good as is other answer with the C# in vsto interop, gui abilities & etc. Just a FYI: VSTO is stable, reliable and useful if you code it properly. Since its a fusion of unmanaged & managed code and you need to know how to manage memory effectively: http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop

Comment: I fail to see with the latest release of VSTO how VB.NET is any easier than C#.

Comment: http://netoffice.codeplex.com/ is a nice, open source wrapper for the Microsoft Office COM APIs. You can use any .NET language to automate office or even write Office add-ins. It works in the free versions of Visual Studio. The resulting add-in is usually compatible with all versions of MS Office from Office 2007 upwards.

Answer (score 7):

VSTO presumes you are using Visual Studio as your development platform, thus mainly targeting professional and corporate developers. 'Power users' who create macros and add-ins with VBA seem not to be the the target audience for VSTO.

If you are interested in add-ins for Excel, the native .xll add-ins have some specific advantages over VSTO, in particular they support creating high-performance user-defined functions. Libraries like [ExcelDna](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) (and ManagedXll which you mention) make it easy to create .xll add-ins for Excel using managed code. Contrary to what OmegaMan says, these .xll-based add-ins do not work through the Automation Add-in interfaces, support Excel versions from '97 to Excel 2010 and allow advanced features that VSTO does not support, like registration-free Ribbon and RTD support.

For creating add-ins for various other office applications, in particular for Outlook, you could also look at [Add-In Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Apples and Oranges....managedxll is for help building automation add-ins and is limited. It only targets office 2003 (AFAIK).

VSTO gives the developer the ability to write C# code directly against the interops of Excel, create smart documents, forms ribbons and add-ins in separate .net assemblies of the .net language of one's choice.

Plus no runtime license is required for use of VSTO.

HTH