# How to update data on opened Excel file with C# application?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-2007

I'd like to start a C# application from Excel 2007 which read and write data in the same opened XLS file.
In this XLS file, I have input data sheets, a button to start my C# application (process or dll) and some sheets to collect results from my C# application in dedicated output sheets.

The user open the XLS file, fill data sheet, and then start on 'compute' button to start my C# application has to read the current XLS file in which it will read data, do some computation, and the write data in new sheet in my same opened Excel file.

Is it possible to do that without intermediate files like .csv or .txt file ?

Which library should I use in C# to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: If you absolutely want to do this in C# you need to look into VSTO, but for performance considerations I'd go with good ol' VBA. Voting to close this question as *too broad* though. Please post on SO when you're stuck on a *specific* issue ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug: without VSTO, it is not possible in C# ? My question is a specific use case.

Comment: See [this similar off-topic Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603101/vsto-alternatives) (possible duplicate even)

Comment: @Mat'sMug: So I sum up : if I want to use c# code I need to use VSTO or alternatives. My goal is not reachable with .exe console app or a classical .dll assembly. You confirms ?

Comment: You could always work with Office's COM interop libraries in a console app if you wanted, but from what you're trying to achieve this looks like a much, much better & simpler job for VBA.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: Just a precision, the computation in my C# application is very complexe and heavy and my code already exists

Comment: Then compile a COM-visible dll, expose the functionality to COM and reference the type library in your VBA project - you'll get the best of both (COM & .NET) worlds!

Comment: @Patrice - is there some reason you don't want to use VSTO in your existing C# app?

Comment: @Tim: No, i've just heard that VSTO needs some configurations than can be a little bit heavy when you don't know VSTO.